# use clang-query to match specified string

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer, clang-query

how should I use clang-query to match specified string
souece code:

```
int main()
{
__asm__ __volatile__("pause");
}
```

I want to substituted "yield" for "pause"

what I have tried
in clang-query, I can only match the stringLiteral and I cant match "pause"

```
match asmStmt(hasDescendant(stringLiteral()))
```

how should I match "pause" in clang-query